Retrieve data from old MySQL installation to a new one
I have a Laravel project. Suddenly, the project was not connecting to the MySQL database. I then realized that the MySQL service was not starting (Windows 11). I tried to start it manually from services.msc but no use. I also tried other methods but nothing worked.
Finally, I uninstalled the MySQL server 8.0 (I'm using MySQL Workbench btw). Before uninstalling, I copied the Data folder from C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\. I've done a new installation of MySQL. The service is now working.
How do I import all the old data in this new installation from that old Data folder? I have the .ibd files of the schema tables in that folder. But from some quick searching, I found that there are also supposed to be .frm files but I cannot find them.
Is there any way possible to retrieve all those old data from that old installation into this new instance?

If you have copied the whole data directory then stop service, replace current datadir and my.ini with saved one, then start service. PS. I hope that you have installed completely the same MySQL version..

I tried to start it manually from services.msc but no use. You'd look on the console messages and error log.
